# Write UTF-8 Chinese characters from R to a CSV on Windows

Tags: r

I'm able to scrape and display Chinese characters like this:

```
pacman::p_load(rvest, stringr)
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", locale="Chinese")

cheese <- read_html("http://www.kekenet.com/read/story/cheese/")

links <- 
cheese %>%
  html_node(".box") %>%
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_nodes("a")

links <- links[grepl("read",links)]

url_pattern <- "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"

links <- str_extract(links, url_pattern)
links <- links[grepl(".shtml",links)]

text <- data.frame(english=as.character(), chinese=as.character(), stringsAsFactors = F)

for(u in links){
  cheese <- read_html(u)
  tmp0 <- 
    cheese %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="qh_en"]') %>%
    html_text()
  tmp0 <- gsub('\"', "", tmp0, fixed = TRUE)

  tmp1 <- 
    cheese %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="qh_zg"]') %>%
    html_text()
  tmp1 <- gsub('\"', "", tmp1, fixed = TRUE)

  if(length(tmp0)==length(tmp1)){
    tmp <- data.frame(english=tmp0, chinese=tmp1, stringsAsFactors = F)

    text <- rbind(text, tmp)

  }
}
```

However, even when I set the file encoding, when I save it to CSV like this

```
write.csv(text, "english_chinese_test.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

the resulting file has values like this instead of Chinese characters:

> 2Ã©Ã¨Â°Ã¨Â¨Â¤oï¿¥Ã©Ã©o1Ã¨Â·ï¿  â€²Ë‰Ã¨Ë‰â€²3Ë‰oÂ¤Â§Â¤Â°ooÃ©ï¿ Â¨3Â¨Ã¨Â§1|Ã¨aÂ·Â±Ã©o|Ã¨3Ë‰Ã¨Â§Ë‰1Ã¨aÂ·Â±aooÃ¨Ë‰â€²Ã¨Â§1Ë‰aooÃ©Ã©ï¿¡Â°Ã©
>   |-Â¤Ã¨oÃ©ï¿¡Â°Ã©ooÂ¨Ã©1Ã¨1Ã¨Â·Ã¨Â¤oÃ¨Â°Ã¨Ë‰â€²aË‰ooÃ¨Î¼Â·ï¿¥Ã¨Ë‰1Ã©ï¿¡aooÂ·Ã¨aï¿¥Â¨Â¤Â°Â±Ã©ï¿¡Â°Ã©Ã¨Â°Â±Ë‰Ã¨Ë‰â€²o1Ã©â€²oÂ±Ã¨Â§Â±Ã©Ã©ï¿ o- Ã¨â€²oÃ©Ã©Ã©ï¿¡1ooÂ°ï¿¥Ã©aoï¿¥Î¼1Â·o
>   "Ã¨Â°Ã¨oÃ¨Ã¨Ã¨Ã¨Â°Ã¨Ë‰â€²Î¼Ë‰o1Ã©â€²oÂ±1ooÂ¤Â§Ã©Ã¨aÂ·Â±Ã¨ï¿ oo
>
> "
>   å¬äº†è¿™ç•ªè¯ï¼Œæ‰€æœ‰äººéƒ½æƒ³åˆ°äº†è‡ªå·±çš„ç”Ÿæ´»ï¼Œå¤§å®¶å®‰é™ä¸‹æ¥ã€‚
>   å‘ƒï¼Œæ°è¥¿å¡æ¸…äº†æ¸…å—“å­ï¼Œæ‰“ç ´äº†å®é™ï¼Œå¤§å®¶å¥½åƒéƒ½åœ¨è°ˆè®ºè‡ªå·±çš„å·¥ä½œï¼Œä½†æ˜¯æˆ‘å¬åˆ°äº†è¿™ä¸ªæ•…äº‹ä»¥åŽï¼Œå´æƒ³åˆ°äº†æˆ‘çš„ä¸ªäººç”Ÿæ´»ã€‚æˆ‘è§‰å¾—æˆ‘ç›®å‰çš„æƒ…å†µï¼Œæˆ‘çš„å®¶åº­å…³ç³»ï¼Œå°±åƒä¸€ä¸ª'æ—§å¥¶é…ª'ï¼Œä¸Šé¢é•¿æ»¡äº†éœ‰èŒã€‚
>   æŸ¯ç‘žç¬‘å‡ºå£°æ¥ï¼Œè¡¨ç¤ºèµžåŒï¼šæˆ‘ä¹Ÿæ˜¯ã€‚æˆ‘ä¹Ÿè®¸æˆ‘çŽ°åœ¨æœ€è¯¥é‡‡å–è¡ŒåŠ¨çš„å°±æ˜¯è®©ä¸€æ®µä¸æ„‰å¿«çš„å…³ç³»å°½å¿«è¿‡åŽ»ã€‚
>   å®‰æ°æ‹‰åé©³é“ï¼šæˆ‘ä¸åŒæ„ä½ çš„è§‚ç‚¹ï¼Œä¹Ÿè®¸è¿™ä¸ª'æ—§å¥¶é…ª'åªæ˜¯ä¸€ç§æ—§çš„è¡Œä¸ºæ–¹å¼ã€‚æˆ‘ä»¬éœ€è¦æ”¾å¼ƒçš„åªæ˜¯å¼•èµ·è¿™ç§çŠ¶å†µçš„æ—§çš„è¡Œä¸ºæ–¹å¼ï¼Œè€Œä¸æ˜¯è¿™ä¸ª'å¥¶é…ª'ã€‚è¿™æ ·æˆ‘ä»¬æ‰ä¼šæœæ›´å¥½çš„æ€ç»´å’Œè¡Œä¸ºæ–¹å¼è½¬å˜ã€‚